# Unable to create menu with contributes.menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to create a menu using the documentation at the link below for contributes.menu.  Actually, I was able to create one menu item, but could not create a second one.  The code excerpt is from my package.json on Windows 10 using VS Code 1.37.0.

So my question is, can someone show me an example of adding two menu items?

-TIA

```
    "contributes": {



"menus": {
        "editor/title": [{
            "title": "Underline Text",
            "when": "editorHasSelection",
            "command": "macros.underline",
            "alt": "markdown.showPreviewToSide",
            "group": "MyGroup@1"
        }]
    },



        "languages": [
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus

Already tried the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example package.json, based on the one in [the tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), that creates two menu items:

```
{
  ...
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.helloWorld",
    "onCommand:extension.helloAnotherWorld"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "extension.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      },
      {
        "command": "extension.helloAnotherWorld",
        "title": "Hello Another World"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "editor/title/context": [
        {
          "command": "extension.helloWorld"
        },
        {
          "command": "extension.helloAnotherWorld"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: @zBernie You're welcome!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Your answer has been checked.  Thanks again.